# Add text box to a map

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm plotting a route of waypoints using ggmap.

I need to add a text box to the map in the top left containing a vector of names that represent each waypoint.

There is no legend like key, just text.  What is the best way to do this?  I've read about annotations and legends but not sure this is the best way.

```
library(qmap)

names<-c("Name1","Name2", "Name3")

ggm <- qmap(location=map.centre,zoom = 15, maptype = 'road')  

  ggm +
    geom_path(data=coords,aes(x=startLon,y=startLat),color="blue",size=2)+
    geom_point(data=way.points,aes(x=as.numeric(X2),y=as.numeric(X1)),
               size=10,color="yellow")+
    geom_text(data=way.points,
              aes(x=as.numeric(X2),y=as.numeric(X1), label=seq_along(X1)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from http://bcb.dfci.harvard.edu/~aedin/courses/R/CDC/maps.html, but it shows a proper legend in the top right using shapes, colors and text. If you could provide you data, this could be tailored to your specific needs.

```
library(ggmap) # for crime data for the example
library(qmap)

data(crime)

violent_crimes <- subset(crime, offense != "auto theft" & offense != 
    "theft" & offense != "burglary")

# rank violent crimes
violent_crimes$offense <- factor(violent_crimes$offense, levels = c("robbery", 
    "aggravated assault", "rape", "murder"))

# restrict to downtown
violent_crimes <- subset(violent_crimes, -95.39681 <= lon & lon <= 
    -95.34188 & 29.73631 <= lat & lat <= 29.784)

HoustonMap <- qmap('houston', zoom = 14,color = 'bw', legend = 'topright')
HoustonMap + geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, 
                            size = offense,colour = offense), 
                            data = violent_crimes )
```

[image]